# reportviewer rdl file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I am using the ReportViewer control to design a report but when I run the project I get this error:

`A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'.`

Here is my code:

```
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sqla = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myConnection.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;

            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.CommandText ="select * from users";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqla.SelectCommand = cmd;

            sqla.Fill(dt);
            sqla.Fill(ds);

            ReportViewer1.Reset();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "reports/allusers.rdl";
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("ds_users",dt);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a "DataSet1" when I created the rdl file so I needed to pass the data this Dataset to render the report. I changed the `ReportDataSource` lines to the following:

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet1";
rds.Value = dt;
```

And that solved the error message.

Comment: Not until after like 2 days if it's not in Q&A form.